# how to get the post id in plugin

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, id, globals

I have a plugin that I'm working on and I'm having trouble getting the post id so jquery can use it. I'm able to get it using the admin_head hook but I'm not sure how I can return it to jquery. I'm not sure if admin_head is what I need since it does not return anything. Not sure if I can use global?

Also this is in the admin screen so not on the front end.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$custom_ID = 0;

function my_custom_admin_head(){
    global $post;
    $custom_ID = $post->ID;
    global $custom_ID;
}
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_admin_head');

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'my_action_javascript' );

function my_action_javascript() {?>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#get-rates-button').click(function(){
          var result = "<?php echo $custom_ID; ?>";
          alert(result);
        }
}
```

Is there a function that I could call from jquery that would be able to return the id from a hook or does someone know of a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code you could something like this:

```
function my_custom_admin_head(){
    global $post;
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var js_post_id =' . $post->ID . ';</script>';


}
```

And then just use the var `js_post_id`. You shoudl try to read about the [script localization function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) and use it.